# Convert a value json in another value/text via php

Tags: php, json, parsing

I have to parse via PHP a JSON value output, in another text value in HTML. Example: the value json "0" must become text html "Closed" , and the value 1 must become "Open".

**JSON CODE**

```
 {
  "state": 1,
},
```

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$urlState = "https://www.foo.com/data.json";                           
$contentsState = file_get_contents($urlState);
$objState=json_decode($contentsState);

$State1 = $objState->items[0]->state;

echo "<p>State: " . $State1 . " </p>";  
?>
```

**HTML OUTPUT RESULT**

```
<p>State: Open</p>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't see any problem

Comment: `echo "<p>State: " . ($State1 ? 'Open' : 'Closed') . " </p>";`

Comment: @misorude maybe turn that into an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the value with str_replace.

```
$State1 = str_replace("0", "Closed", str_replace("1", "Open", $objState->items[0]->state));
```

This assumes the state is always 1 or 0 and not some string value that could include a 1 or 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
$json = '{ "state": 1}';
$state = (json_decode($json))->state;
echo $state ? "<p>State: Open</p>" : "<p>State: Close</p>";
```